# Why's an "Adjusted Option 10 Shares per contract" offered for just Jan 15 2021?

Tags: call-options

[A contract covers 100 shares of the underlying stock](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/optionscontract.asp), but this is my first time chancing on an Adjusted Option. We clicked "Click here for help", but Questrade's link is broken and no useful information appeared.

1. Please see the title in the question.
2. What's special about 15 Jan 2021? Why  aren't Adjusted Options being sold for other expiry dates?
3. Why are normal and this Adjusted Option being sold together?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any existing options were adjusted for a stock split in Jan, 2019. It's possible that these were long dated options that were bought before the split, and are the only remaining adjusted options left that have not been closed.

Note that adjusted options are equivalent to post-split options, so you are buying an option for 1/10 the shares for the same premium.

In other words, a pre-split option with a $2 strike is equivalent to a post-split option with a $20 strike (for 1/10 the number of shares). There's no difference value-wise, but may be different in terms of liquidity (bid/ask spread).

Answer (score 0):

STNG did a 1:10 reverse split in January of 2019.  At that time, the months available for options were Feb, Mar, Apr, Jul and Oct of 2019 as well as the LEAPs for Jan 2020 and Jan 2021.  It's now May of 2020 so the only adjusted series that has not yet expired is Jan 15, 2021.

The correct title would be **Why are adjusted options offered for only January of 2021** not **for just one strike price** because there are 9 strike prices available for that series, ranging from $0.50 to $5.00

Comment: Thanks for your last para. I rectified my title!